# How to fetch data from string after using serialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html

I am having a form and fetching all field values through this jquery code

> `var adtitletoshow = $("#form_data").serialize();`

Now when i alert `adtitletoshow` its shows something like this -

```
&fomdata1=textone&fomdata2=texttwo&fomdata3=textthree&fomdata4=textfour&fomdata5=textfive
```

Now when i put this code -

```
$("#previewdiv").text(adtitletoshow);
```

Its showing the whole data string. But i only want to show fomdata3 text in this div. How could i achieve this? or their is another better solution for parsing form data as i have to generate a preview of the form data?

Comment: why do you serialize the data?

Comment: @BastianRang just to fetch all data from form before submit to create a preview with those form values

Comment: the answer from akmon should do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of serialize() use serializeArray().

```
var adtitletoshow = $("#form_data").serializeArray();
$.each(adtitletoshow, function(i, field){
  if( field.name == 'fomdata3'){
    $("#previewdiv").text(field.value);
    break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just transform form data to array, not string:

```
 var unindexed_array = $("#form_data").serializeArray();
 vat indexed_array = {};

 $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
     indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var formdata3 = $('#form_data :input[name="fomdata3"]').val();
$("#previewdiv").text(formdata3);
```